# Jekyll page generator causes git warning - fatal: ambiguous argument: unknown revision or path not in the working tree

Tags: ruby, git, github, markdown, jekyll

I'm using Jekyll to build my static web-site. The source code is on GitHub. Further, I have a one big markdown (.md) file from which I'm generating build-time multiple smaller pages. This is done by a simple Jekyll plugin (Jekyll generator).

Everything works as a charm, except the fact I'm getting multiple (for every single page generated build-time) warnings:

```
fatal: ambiguous argument '<path-to-generated-file-here.md>': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'
```

The ruby version s 2.3.0, but I think this is related to git especially, not Jekyll itself.

I'm not doing any 'git diff' or something else. I even tried to add the folder in which the .md files are generated to .gitignore, but to no avail.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated, because I'm really stuck! :)

Comment: Repository url please ?

Comment: it is a private repo and I cannot give you access to it :(

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve] of the problem? We don't need to see the entire contents of a large private repo. Can you recreate the issue in a *minimal* way?

Comment: So, no code, no debug !

Comment: A wild guess: your template uses something like "last updated at" which tries to fetch date of last commit affecting the file from git, but it cannot find it, because those files are not checked into git.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys! The issue was caused because of another plugin I'm using (for the sitemap.xml lastMod tag) - it traverses all site.html_pages and gets the timestamp of the htmlPage.url...but since the files are generated before that (when the Jekyll generators are being processed) and are not actually on the source, a "git log" command triggers and outputs it. So...if anyone has such an issue... check for "git log..", "git diff.."